# How do you extract every 5th frame from an .mp4 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mp4, video-processing

I'm building a web app that uploads a local .mp4 to an S3 bucket. It's intended for low bandwidth environments. Is it possible to upload every 5th frame of an .mp4 in JavaScript on the frontend and upload this reduced .mp4?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible (I didn't find anything online) but it's certainly not easy.
It would be easier to maybe have an endpoint in a server that receives a video and returns a minified version. Like this:

- Client --can you minify this video?---> Server
- Client <--minified video---- Server
- Client ---upload minified video---> S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible. Frames are not independent. Uploading a frame, without uploading the frames it references will crate a corrupt video.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to extract the frames just as jpegs and upload them and then recombine into a .mp4 on the server?

Comment: You would need to pull in a full transcoder like ffmpeg.js. It would take a lot of time to run in the browser, and you probably won't save any bandwidth. Due to temporal redundancy, the combined size of the jpegs would probably be larger than the mp4, because only the difference in the frames are encoded in mp4.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of FFMPEG in your browser in fact. From ffmpeg.wasm:

> ffmpeg.wasm is a pure Webassembly / Javascript port of FFmpeg. It
> enables video & audio record, convert and stream right inside
> browsers.

Check out the different parameters in regards to your nth frame rate from the documentation on [FFMPEG.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate).

PS: It might be better solutions to shrink the upload size, ie. compress harder, resize the video dimensions, or combinations of all these, including lowering the frame rate.